# Need Help Displaying Percentage Sign in C++

Tags: c++, formatting

Essentially, I want the output to look like the first photo, but my output is in the 2nd (both attached). I attached my code snippet as well to show what I am trying.

Any help would be appreciated, I have solved all logical errors in this program and just need help formatting. Also, is there any better way to keep all of the inputs and calculated values on the right side, or do I just need to throw in the \t a couple times like I did? Thanks!

[I want my code to look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYzja.png)

[But keep getting this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmVIw.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

double loanAmount, interestRate, paymentsNum;

    //Stores the loan amount value into memory
    cout << "Loan Amount: \t\t\t$ ";
    cin >> loanAmount;

    //Stores the monthly interest rate value into memory
    cout << "Monthly Interest Rate: \t\t";
    cin >> interestRate; cout << '%' << endl;
    interestRate = interestRate / 100;

    //Stores the nuumber of payments value into memory
    cout << "Number of Payments: \t\t";
    cin >> paymentsNum;

    //Calculates the payment on a loan
    double payment = (interestRate * pow((1 + interestRate), paymentsNum)) / (pow((1 + interestRate), paymentsNum) - 1);

    //Calculates the monthly payment on a loan
    double monthlyPayment = payment * loanAmount;
    cout << "Monthly Payment: \t\t$ " << monthlyPayment << endl;

    //Calculates the total amount paid back from the original loan amount
    double paidBack = monthlyPayment * paymentsNum;
    cout << "Amount Paid Back: \t\t$ " << paidBack << endl;

    //Calculates the total interest paid on the loan
    double interestPaid = paidBack - loanAmount;
    cout << "Interest Paid: \t\t\t$ " << interestPaid << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This happens because the program cannot receive the input until you press the `Enter` key, but this makes the output go to the next line. This is a limitation of the terminal and not something you can handle with ordinary use of `cin` and `cout`. Try asking for all the desired input in one stage, and then displaying all appropriate output afterwards. Try using a function to prompt the user for a line of input and then examine what was typed in. Do not expect to be able to "decorate" the input.

Comment: On the topic of posting on Stack Overflow: [Please do not upload images of textual output (expected or actual) when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste it (or type it out) as text, formatted like code.

Comment: `pow((1 + interestRate), paymentsNum)` -- Off-topic, but instead of calling this twice, compute this once, store it in a variable, and use that variable.

Comment: I suggest you do all your calculations first, and then figure out how to format the output.  It gets confusing by having a calculation done, then an output, then a calculation, then an output, etc.   The code would look a little more organized, at the very least.  Also, your code uses absolutely no formatting in the output statements.  Using tab, isn't going to be enough.  You should investigate [<iomanip>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), and experiment with it (see `std::setfill()`, `std::ios::left`, `setw`, and `std::ios::right`), etc. to attempt to obtain the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> interestRate;
```

At this point your program stops and waits for you to type a line of text following by the `Enter` key, which gets echoed back, the `Enter` key causes the cursor to move to the next line.

```
cout << '%' << endl;
```

Only after the cursor moves to the next line does this output take place. The fact that in the source file this statement is on the same line is immaterial. The output of the C++ program does not depend on how its source code is formatted, C++ does not work this way. C++ is whitespace-agnostic, a C++ program can be indented in any way and its spacing is completely arbitrary, without affecting its functionality.

It is not possible to get the behavior you want from a basic C++ program that uses basic C++ input and output, via `std::cin` and `std::cout`, in a portable manner. On an outside chance you can consult the documentation for your operating system, to determine if there are special terminal character sequences that can be used to move the cursor to the previous line and position it at a (guessed) column where the `%` would go. This would be specific not just to your operating system but also to whatever terminal program you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround to this. To get my desired output I used:

```
cout << "Loan Amount: " << right << setw(20) << "$ ";
cin << loanAmount;

cout << "Monthly Interest Rate: " << setw(12) << "%\b\b";
cin >> interestRate;
interstRate = interestRate / 100;
```

Not sure if this is the best idea, but it worked. I'm not too worried about fixing this minor issue, but I ended up just stumbling upon this again while watching some videos online.